# Where does predefined macros reside in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, preprocessor, language-concepts, predefined-macro

I  wonder where are predefined macros are defined and resided in?

Predefined macros are defined in compiler or preprocessor which has a dictionary that hold the pre-defined macros in the source code.

I mean `__FILE__` macro has a definition and equivalence value in the compiler and the definition has been made in the compiler is it true?

Comment: `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and others are replaced by the *preprocessor* at the time of preprocessing, just as all other macros.

Comment: Yes that is true but their definition has made in the preprocessor's source code ?

Comment: They aren't defined anywhere. How do you think that would work?

Comment: They are built into the preprocessor and effectively act as keywords.

Comment: See e.g. [Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) for GCC, other compilers do the same.

Comment: for example  __STDC_VERSION__  has a value  and it is defined according to its version so the definition should be defined somewhere in the compiler source code

Comment: @bool3max I acctually mean source code of a compiler has an equivalance value of predefined macros.

Comment: @Nazim It is far from clear what you're actualy asking here. *Of course* the predefined macros will manifest themselves in the source code of the preprocessor, somehow or other. Otherwise they wouldn't work. But exactly how they do that is up to the author in each case, and probably varies with the actual macro as well.

Comment: They are not macros in the traditional sense. A macro usually expands to a fixed value. But `__FILE__/__LINE__` expands to the current file/line, which varies depending on the file/line compiler is currently dealing with.

Answer (score 4):

[**The C Preprocessor**, For GCC Version 9.2.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/cpp.pdf), Chapter 3.7 (Predefined Macros) says:

> Several object-like macros are predefined; you use them without supplying their definitions.

and later, for example

> **__LINE__** -- This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a decimal integer  constant.   While  we  call  it  a  predefined  macro,  it’s  a  pretty  strange macro, since its “definition” changes with each new line of source code

---

Meaning that there are no concrete definitions of these macros anywhere. During preprocessing time, the C preprocessor keeps track of which file it is currently processing and replaces `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and other "special" macros accordingly.

Comment: it does not explain the question: "where do those macros come from?". Is it compiled in? Or not?

Comment: I don't understand how it does not. The preprocessor supplies the definitions itself, I think that's pretty clear. The first quote says that. What do you mean by "compiled in"?